# D3.js: German dates

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

Is there any way to convert the x-axis in the following example to non-english (e.g. german):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306234) may also help.

Comment: Actually, this changes the months from October to Oktober, but in that example the time is still in AM/PM!

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You may want to file this.

Answer (score 0):

Here the way to to it:

```
git clone git@github.com:mbostock/d3.git
cd d3
npm install
sudo locale-gen
LOCALE=de_DE.UTF-8 make clean all
```